# Laravel foreach problem when trying to convert XML format

Tags: php, xml, laravel, foreach

i'm stuck on a problem.

I'm trying to create a report of customers daily transaction's and convert the final result to XML to send SMS.

Here is my function to create report and convert to XML.

```
public function dailyReport()
    {
        // Get all customers.
        $customers = DB::table('customers')->get();

        // Get all transaction records for each customer.
        $report = [];
        foreach ($customers as $customer) {
            $transactions = DB::table('transactions')
                ->where('customer_id', $customer->id)
                ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
                ->get();

            // Calculate the customer's daily sales, returns and collections
            $sales = 0;
            $returns = 0;
            $collections = 0;
            foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
                $sales += $transaction->amount;
                $returns += $transaction->return;
                $collections += $transaction->collect;
            }

            // Create daily transaction report for each customer
            $customerReport = [
                'name' => $customer->name,
                'phone' => $customer->phone,
                'sales' => $sales,
                'returns' => $returns,
                'collections' => $collections,
                'total' => $sales - $returns - $collections,
            ];

            $report[] = $customerReport;
        }

        // Create the report as XML
        $xml = ArrayToXml::convert(['report' => $report], 'report');

        // Encoding and Decoding the XML
        $xmlArray = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml)), true)['report'];

        // Send SMS for each report
        foreach ($xmlArray as $record) {
            $message = "Hello, " . $record['name'] . " \n"
                . "on " . Carbon::today()->toDateString()
                . "\nYou bought a product worth " . $record['sales'] . " USD,"
                . "\nYou refunded " . $record['returns'] . "USD,"
                . "\nYou paid" . $record['collections'] . "USD,"
                . "\nYour total balance: " . $record['total'] . "USD"
                . "\nFor your informations.";

            $xmlData = [
                'username' => env('GSM_USERNAME'),
                'password' => env('GSM_PASSWORD'),
                'header' => 'header',
                'validity' => 2880,
                'message' => [
                    'gsm' => [
                        'no' => [
                            $record['phone'],
                            $record['phone']
                        ],

                    ],
                    'msg' => [
                        '@cdata' => $message,
                    ],
                ],
            ];

            $options = ['rootElementName' => 'sms'];

            $xml = ArrayToXml::convert($xmlData, $options);
            // To send to SMS call the function
            $response = $this->sendSMS($xml);

            echo $response;
        }
    }
```

And my transaction migration:

```
        Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->integer('amount');
            $table->integer('return');
            $table->integer('collect');
            $table->string('customer_responsible');
            $table->string('employee');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

When I'm trying to send request from postman it returns
"ErrorException: Array to string conversion in file C:\my_app\app\Http\Controllers\TransactionController.php on line 143"

And line 143 is: `$message = "Hello, " . $record['name'] . " \n"`

dd($xml) result is:

```
<report>
    <report>
        <name>John Doe Market</name>
        <phone>+9015235205</phone>
        <sales>120320</sales>
        <returns>1547</returns>
        <collections>3821</collections>
        <total>114952</total>
    </report>
    <report>
        <name></name>
        <phone></phone>
        <sales>0</sales>
        <returns>0</returns>
        <collections>0</collections>
        <total>0</total>
    </report>
</report>
```

and dd($record) is:

```
array:6 [ // app\Http\Controllers\TransactionController.php:143
  "name" => "John Doe Market"
  "phone" => "+9015235205"
  "sales" => "120320"
  "returns" => "1547"
  "collections" => "3821"
  "total" => "114952"
]
```

I think the problem has been occure for

```
foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
                $sales += $transaction->amount;
                $returns += $transaction->return;
                $collections += $transaction->collect;
            }
```

But i'm unable to solve. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solve the problem. The problem's source is customers that have not transactions. So, empty array occures that error.

New question is, how can I pass the empty arrays and keep it continue and block the error?